# How to set the Title of a Frame in java via Combobox?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, actionlistener, jcombobox

I want to create something like the image below, when the user select the year, the month and the day from the Combobox options, those actions will change the Title and it has to change according to the selected data, it's something simple, I am still newbie

[image]

So far I have done this, the problem is that it does't work, how can I make it?, could you help me please?

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class DateForm_Complete extends JFrame {

    private JLabel          year, month, day;
    private JComboBox       cmonth, cday, cyear;

    public DateForm_Complete() {

        setTitle("Date Selection");
        setSize(400,100);
        setupWidgets();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setupWidgets() {
        year=   new JLabel("Year");
        month=  new JLabel("Month");
        day=    new JLabel("Day");
        cyear=  new JComboBox();
        cmonth= new JComboBox();
        cday=   new JComboBox();

        setLayout(new GridLayout (2,3));

        add(year);   add(month);    add(day);
        add(cyear);  add(cmonth);   add(cday);

        for (int i=1900; i<2019; i++)   
        {
            cyear.addItem(i);
        }

        String months[] = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};

        for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            cmonth.addItem(months[i]);
        }

        for (int i=1; i<32; i++)    
        {
            cday.addItem(i);
        }
        setupEvents();
    }

    private void setupEvents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        cyear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                JComboBox combo = (JComboBox)ev.getSource();
                String texty = (String)combo.getSelectedItem(); 
            }
        });

        cmonth.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                JComboBox combo = (JComboBox)ev.getSource();
                String textm = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();
            }
        });

        cday.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                JComboBox combo = (JComboBox)ev.getSource();
                String textd = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();     
            }
        });
        setTitle("Today is "+ texd+ "of "+ textm + "of " +texty);               
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new DateForm_Complete();        
    }
}
```

Comment: Given a reference to `JFrame`, just call it's `setTitle` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever an item in a combo box is selected you need to reset the entire string you want to display as the title.

So, you need a method in your class like:

```
public void changeTitle()
{
    String year = cyear.getSeletedItem().toString();
    String month = cmonth.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String day = cday.getSelectedItem().toString();

    setTitle("Today is "+ day + "of "+ month + "of " + year);      
}
```

Then from the 3 ActionListeners you just invoke the `changTitle()` method.`

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed few things in your code and now it works. Try and see. Main changes are:

In `setTitle("Today is "+ texd+ "of "+ textm + "of " +texty);` in your code, variables `textd`, `textm` and `texty` are out of scope (meaning they are declared inside each `actionPerformed()` method. So they are not available/visible outside those `actionPerformed()` methods.). So I made them instance variables of `DateForm_Complete` class.

Then I called `setTitle("Today is "+ textd+ " of "+ textm + " of " +texty);` from each `actionPerformed()` method. Because I guess your requirement is to update the title as soon as each combo box value is changed.

There was a typo in `texd` variable name as well.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DateForm_Complete extends JFrame {

  private JLabel          year, month, day;
  private JComboBox       cmonth, cday, cyear;

  private String texty = "1900";
  private String textm = "January";
  private String textd = "1";

  public DateForm_Complete() {

    setTitle("Date Selection");
    setSize(400,100);
    setupWidgets();
    setVisible(true);
  }

  private void setupWidgets() {
    year=   new JLabel("Year");
    month=  new JLabel("Month");
    day=    new JLabel("Day");
    cyear=  new JComboBox();
    cmonth= new JComboBox();
    cday=   new JComboBox();

    setLayout(new GridLayout (2,3));

    add(year);   add(month);    add(day);
    add(cyear);  add(cmonth);   add(cday);

    for (int i=1900; i<2019; i++)
    {
      cyear.addItem(i);
    }

    String months[] = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};

    for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
      cmonth.addItem(months[i]);
    }

    for (int i=1; i<32; i++)
    {
      cday.addItem(i);
    }
    setupEvents();
  }

  private void setupEvents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    cyear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        JComboBox combo = (JComboBox)ev.getSource();
        texty = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        setTitle("Today is "+ textd+ " of "+ textm + " of " +texty);
      }
    });

    cmonth.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        JComboBox combo = (JComboBox)ev.getSource();
        textm = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();
        setTitle("Today is "+ textd+ " of "+ textm + " of " +texty);
      }
    });

    cday.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        JComboBox combo = (JComboBox)ev.getSource();
        textd = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        setTitle("Today is "+ textd+ " of "+ textm + " of " +texty);
      }
    });

  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    new DateForm_Complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: (1-) Yes this would work, but why would create unnecessary instance variables and repeat the code for resetting the title?. What if you ever want to change the format of the title to be something like year, month and day? Now you need to change the code in 3 places. Use methods to simplify the code and reduce duplication of code.

Comment: `I've fixed few things in your code and now it works` - also, just posting code without an explanation doesn't help the OP understand what you changed or why you changed it.

Comment: @camickr, yes there are many things I could improve in this code from design perspective. But I just wanted to give a working solution with minimum changes (without rewriting it).

Comment: @camickr, sometimes, especially to new developers, it helps to show working code than explanations. And since my code has only few changes, OP will be able to compare and see what he/she did wrong.

Comment: All answers should have some kind of explanation about what the solution is, not just a code dump. Especially for new developers so they can understand the context/reason for the changes. Just looking at the differences they may not understand why it works.

Comment: @camickr, ok. I'll edit my answer and add some explanation. Thanks.